# How do you catch a returning boomerang without hurting yourself?

Tags: dont-starve

The boomerang seems like an incredibly useful weapon, being the only ranged reusable weapon in the game so far. Using it is, however, a (quite literally) a pain in the ass, as the weapon has a nasty habit of hitting yourself when returning. How do you catch the returning boomerang properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The boomerang will always return to you, so there's no point in dodging it. To catch it properly you need to hold down <kbd>Space</kbd> when it's near. This will prevent boomerang from hitting you in the ass, and reduce its wear by half.

Comment: This is correct. Be careful to hit space on the right moment: if you're near an other object where space makes sense (for example, twigs), pressing space too soon might cause your character to go harvest twigs instead (and surprise, receive a boomerang in the face). Let the boomerang get close enough.

Comment: Is there a way to catch the boomerang with a mouse click, or is the spacebar the only reliable way to catch it?